# Spring Boot unknown column 'INNER. ' in order clause

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA to get data from a MySQL database. I have this function adnotated with @Query in a repository

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM  Treatments INNER JOIN Animals ON Treatments.animal_id = Animals.animal_id WHERE Animals.owner_id = ?1 AND Treatments.enddate > curdate()", nativeQuery = true)
        Page<Treatments> findAll(@Param("ownerId") Optional<Owner> owner, Pageable pageable);
```

Spring generates the SQL as it is, then adds `order by INNER.startdate asc limit ?`
And then it throws this error
`Unknown column 'INNER.startdate' in 'order clause'`
Why is this happening? I tried adding an orderby clause myself but it will just add its own orderby clause anyway and throw the error. The query works inside MySql.

Comment: in the Query you wrote, I see no "order by". Does Spring adds this by its own?

Comment: yes, it adds it by its own, I've enabled spring.jpa.show-sql=true and can see it. it generates my sql then just adds that order by

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe that is always done for native queries. Could you write instead a non-native query? Something like @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM  Treatments INNER JOIN Animals ON Treatments.animal_id = Animals.animal_id WHERE Animals.owner_id = :ownerId AND Treatments.enddate > curdate()")
        Page<Treatments> findAll(@Param("ownerId") Optional<Owner> owner, Pageable pageable);

Comment: It seems like it somehow interprets "INNER" as an alias to the table name "Treatments". You don't have an explicit alias for that table, so perhaps adding one would help the interpreter? I.e. change the query to "SELECT * FROM  Treatments as t INNER JOIN..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose Spring modifies your query because you use `Page` as the return type. When you use a native query together with `Page`, you should add a `countQuery`, see [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query.native).

Comment: works good now with countQuery and aliases

Answer (score 0):

My version spring boot: 2.3.12.RELEASE

Define exactly which columns need to be selected and redefine column name again(`SELECT Treatments.animal_id AS animal_id,..`). Trust me, don't missing `AS`

Not working with `SELECT Treatments.animal_id,..` OR `SELECT Treatments.animal_id animal_id,..`

You need this native query:

```sql
SELECT Treatments.animal_id AS animal_id, Treatments.enddate AS enddate, Animals.owner_id AS owner_id
FROM  Treatments INNER JOIN Animals
ON Treatments.animal_id = Animals.animal_id
WHERE Animals.owner_id = ?1 AND Treatments.enddate > curdate()
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT m.* FROM (
    SELECT a.animal_id AS animal_id, a.enddate AS enddate, b.owner_id AS owner_id
    FROM  Treatments a INNER JOIN Animals b ON a.animal_id = b.animal_id
) AS m WHERE owner_id = ?1 AND enddate > curdate()
```